# Audio/Video broadcasting via Python

Tags: python, html, stream, python-3.x, broadcast

so i have been racking my brain with trying to get an audio/video broadcasting method going with python.

I have done allot of research, hit google up quite a bit, and found a few audio broadcasting methods, but those are simply for mp3 based broadcasting systems.

What I am looking to do, is broadcast with python (audio/video) that will play in sync together to an audience (much like ustream).

If anyone could shed some light on this situation, I would be greatly appreciative!

Also, if there is a way that this could be done via HTML 5, that would be even more fantastic

Comment: Python is a server-side technology. If this is an in-browser broadcast, what is playing the video? Flash? Java?

Comment: A stream is just bytes that you read from someplace and write somewhere else. It's pretty easy in any language, and most easily done  with existing software, such as a web server. So I don't know what the question is, really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And what about gstreamer?

http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/

I already read about a lot of projects using gstreamer to stream video and audio :
http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/01/streaming_audio_over_tcp_with_python-gstreamer/

http://blog.abourget.net/2009/6/14/gstreamer-rtp-and-live-streaming/

Gstreamer woiuld be the server part of the application. 
To catch the stream, you'll need a plugin.

I think about vlc for example : 
http://wiki.videolan.org/HowTo_Integrate_VLC_plugin_in_your_webpage

I know that the vlc plugin and gstreamer can work together, I experienced it myself in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Not strictly a Python example, but [this blog post](http://css.dzone.com/articles/face-detection-using-html5) documents how to build a web app that streams webcam video to an HTML5 video player. Chrome especially seems to make playing streaming video very easy.